# Configurar una red en Git para trabajo colaborativo

Tags: git

Quiero armar una red usando git para los repositorios, pero no en forma local si no que de alguna forma haya un servidor y que los demás compañeros conectados desde su casa hagan sus respectivos cambios. Tengo una PC que lo puedo usar como servidor, pero no estará prendido las 24 horas. Como si estuviera en GitHub pero en modo local. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Puedes usar [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) de manera gratuita para repos privados. De ahí en fuera **git** trabaja justo como todo lo que necesitas, la pregunta aquí no es necesaria. Puedes buscar como montar un servidor en git en San Google.

Comment: Como bien comenta @Chofoteddy es mucho mejor usar Bitbucket, pero si por alguna situación no te funciona/conviene tener una cuenta ahí aquí hay una pequeña guía https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH o si son solo dos usuarios puedes usar http://gitstack.com/

Comment: Hola Santiago, lamentablemente las preguntas sobre recomendaciones de software son subjetivas, no son apropiadas para este sitio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes ver [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/), es un servidor para repositorios desarrollado en java, por tanto puede ser utilizado en windows, linux y mac (incluso en otros) tambien tiene una version WAR, que se puede desplegar en un contenedor de aplicaciones Java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente es facil de configurar y de usar, y tiene las carateristicas basicas que todos necesitan

- Crear usuarios
- Etiquetas
- Ventana de actividades
- Pull-Request
- Un code-diff
- Posibilidad de integrar sevicios de tickets como thebuggenie

Puedes ver una demo [aqui](https://dev.gitblit.com/)

*Traducción de la instalación de la versión GO*

> - Descargar y descomprimir Gitblit GO 1.7.1 (Windows) o 1.7.1 (Linux / OSX). Lo mejor es eliminar espacios en el nombre de la ruta.
> - Si el servidor se configura a través de un archivo de texto simple. Abra el archivo `data/gitblit.properties` en su editor de texto
>     favorito y asegúrese de revisar y ajustar: • `server.httpPort` y
>     `server.httpsPort` • `server.storePassword` (no escriba # caracteres)
> - git.packedGitLimit (fija más grande que el tamaño de su repositorio más grande)
> - Ejecutar authority.cmd o java -cp gitblit.jar com.gitblit.authority.Launcher --base datos de carpeta desde una línea
>     de comandos
>
>   - Rellenar los campos en el nuevo diálogo de valores predeterminados de certificados
>   - Introduzca la contraseña del almacén utilizado en `server.storePassword` cuando se le solicite. Esto genera un
>       certificado SSL para localhost.
>   - es posible que desee generar un certificado SSL para el nombre de host o ip nombres de host de dirección que está sirviendo de NOTA:
>       Sólo puede tener un certificado SSL especificado para un puerto.
>   - Salga de la aplicación de la autoridad
> - Ejecutar gitblit.cmd o java -jar gitblit.jar --baseFolder datos desde una línea de comandos
> - Abra su navegador a `http://localhost:8080` o `https://localhost:8443` dependiendo de la configuración elegida.
> - Introduzca las credenciales de administrador por defecto: `admin` / `admin` y haga clic en el botón Iniciar sesión
>
> **NOTA:** Asegúrese de cambiar el nombre de usuario y / o contraseña de administrador !!

*Traducción de la version WAR*

> - Descargar Gitblit WAR 1.7.1 a la carpeta webapps de su contenedor de servlets. [1 ver nota abajo]
> - Puede que tenga que extraer manualmente el WAR (archivo zip) a una carpeta dentro de la carpeta webapps.
> - Por defecto, la aplicación web Gitblit se configura a través de `WEB-INF/ data/gitblit.properties`. Abrir
>     `WEB-INF/data/gitblit.properties` en su editor de texto favorito y
>     asegúrese de revisar y ajustar:  `git.packedGitLimit` (fija más grande
>     que el tamaño de su repositorio más grande)
>
>   4. Es posible que tenga que reiniciar el contenedor de servlets.
>   5. Abra su navegador en `http://localhost/gitblit` o la dirección que tenga su contenedor de aplicaciones.
>   6. Introduzca las credenciales de administrador por defecto: admin / admin y haga clic en el botón Iniciar sesión
>
> **NOTA:** Asegúrese de cambiar el nombre de usuario y / o contraseña de administrador !!

**Nota 1:** Glassfish o Apache Tomcat deberia funcionar como contenedor, puedes ver su instalacion en los siguientes tutoriales:

- [Video Apache tomcat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dPvsL32lPs)
- [Tutorial Galssfish](http://jpreda.blogspot.mx/2013/12/oracle-como-instalar-oracle-glassfish.html)

Answer (score 8):

Git puede funcionar así sin otro software.  Hay tres opciones de protocolos que puedes usar, según [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Los-Protocolos):

- [HTTP/S](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Los-Protocolos#El-protocolo-HTTP/S)
- [SSH](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Los-Protocolos#El-Procotolo-SSH)
- [Protocolo Git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Los-Protocolos#El-Protocolo-Git)

En tu caso, el protocolo Git puede ser lo más razonable, porque es parte de git, y así no requiere otro software.

> El protocolo Git es un demonio (daemon) especial, que viene incorporado con Git. Escucha por un puerto dedicado (9418), y nos da un servicio similar al del protocolo SSH; pero sin ningún tipo de autentificación.

Si quieres autentificación, puedes considerar usar SSH.

El capítulo [Git en un servidor](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor), del libro *Pro Git*, explica como instalar git para usar el protocolo git, y SSH.

Es importante entender que esto solo sirve como servidor para Git; no incluye la interfaz web como GitHub. Por eso, hay varias opciones, como [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home), y otros.  También hay opciones con interfaces web más simples, como [GitWeb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb), que puedes usar en conjunción con con tu servidor de Git.  Pero no puedo hacer una recomendación especifico por estos, porque la opción mejor para ti depende mucho en tu caso, tu presupuesto, y tus preferencias.

Comment: Por como veo la opción de ir a por SSH es la que mas se usa, pero es la mejor?, para mi caso seria una buena opción esta?.

Comment: @Santiago eso depende mucho de tus necesidades. Puedes editar tu pregunta para especificar mas tus necesidades, limitaciones, preferencias, uso, etc. y, con ello, responderte mas acertadamente.

Answer (score 2):

Estimado puedes utilizar **Gitolite**

***Ventajas***

- Fácil de configurar
- Fácil de utilizar
- No necesita un servidor 24/7
- Mucha documentación
- Git puro

***Desventajas***

- Solo en linux distro: Ubuntu(Probado)
- Conocimiento de permisos, usuarios y grupos en linux

Para más información http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html.

Comment: Lamentablemente estamos con windows o mac.

Comment: Pero el servidor lo podes instalar en linux ??? o el servidor es un windows server ?

Comment: Son clientes normales windows y mac, y el problema es que no estan familiarizados con linux y yo solo tengo conocimientos básicos.

Comment: Podes poner el servidor en linux, y los clientes no se ven afectados, es una herramienta muy práctica. te sugiero que la pruebes